# Analog power filtering - Island or direct connection?

Tags: analog, filter

Normally for an analog section, the supply voltage is filtered with a ferrite bead and a capacitor. Now my questions is, makes it sense to use a VCC_Analog island and connect every IC directly with a VIA to it at the power pin (ofc. there will be additional a decoupling cap) or would it makes sense to use a separate power trace to each individual IC?

[image]

Of this two variants I tend to use Variant 1, since it has way less inductance and also forms a higher capacitance between GND and the power plane.

Additionally to note, both will use the same solid ground plane and are only separated spacially.